# With a binary Y, why are R's lowess fits so often flat?

Tags: r, loess

I'm trying to explore (rather than formally test) relationships for various subgroups between a continuous X and a binary Y (0 or 1). A good shortcut would seem to be to graph a smoothed X-Y fit for each subgroup.  But even when, at various levels of X, the mean of Y ranges from .1 to .3, R's smoothed fitline often simply hugs the horizontal where Y=0.  This is not informative at all and in fact seems inaccurate.

I've tried several different ways to obtain a smoother as well as many different values of f.  E.g.:

```
x=runif(500,0,1)  #x is continuous
y=1:500
y=ifelse(y < 100,1,0)  #y is now binary with mean ~ 0.2

z=1:500
z=ifelse(z<50 | (z<300 & z>100),1,0)  #z is binary too


plot(x [z==1], y [z==1])
m=lowess(x[z==1], y[z==1])
lines(m, col='blue')  #The line hugs the points at y=0
windows()
scatter.smooth(x [z==1], y[z==1])
```

In this case this last line did produce the expected sort of fitline, but it's not a reliable occurrence when I work with real data.

Answer (score 2):

It works consistently fine for me.

```
y <- rbinom(100, 1, (0:99)/100)
x <- 1:100
m <- loess(y~x)
plot(y ~ x)
lines(predict(m)) # also illustrating the newer loess function that has different defaults
lines(lowess(x,y), col = 'blue')
```

If you run that a few times you'll notice the blue line does tend to stick closer to the 0s at the low x-values and 1s at the higher ones.  But different defaults in lowess will change that.  Raise the span from the default (2/3) to 0.75 and it will tend to do it less.

```
lines(lowess(x,y, f = 0.75), col = 'blue')
```

(`loess` is generally preferred over `lowess` these days.  It has many more options and is more advanced.)

Comment: (+1) Helpful answer, and for your data I'm getting things to work fine, but after extensive trials I'm still finding these various commands to work inconsistently. loess, lowess, and scatter.smooth may or may not work on any given trial.  Different levels of "f" or "span" may fail to yield different degrees of smoothing (or else may fail to produce lines at all).  It's enough to make a person yearn for SPSS :-)

Comment: It's just a matter of understanding what algorithm you're using and how it responds to various forms of data.  There are more options than span to think about.  Stick with loess if you're longing for SPSS (used by scatter.smooth, so they should be consistent). It's defaults will rarely, if ever, steer you wrong.  If you're not seeing curves you expect with loess the odds are very high you have the wrong expectations.

Comment: I appreciate that advice.  I'd still like to know why for me, with my code above, scatter.smooth consistently produces the expected fitline hovering around the actual y mean of 0.2, whereas lowess and loess both consistently fail to do so at various values of "f" or "span", respectively.

Comment: My guess is that scatter.smooth selects settings for loess based on the data that will look good in a scatter plot.

Comment: I've found that the plsmo command used with the Hmisc package in R provides an excellent solution.  Not only are the smoothed lines more sensible, but the graphs provide for separate lines for subgroups, with tick marks indicating the N-sizes at different levels of X.  http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hmisc/docs/plsmo